# Rails fields_for returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fields-for

Think I've solved this in the process of writing it. I'll post my solution below.

tl;dr Rails fields_for not generating the expected params.

I have a User class, with the following code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :woojit, dependent: :destroy, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :woojit

  # ... more
end
```

and a Woojit class

```
class Woojit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Our UsersController includes this method (we're using the gem Administrate, but it's a subclass of Rails' ApplicationController):

```
class WoojitsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def new
    # ... other stuff
    @woojit = @user.build_woojit
  end
end
```

And our user _form.html.erb partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for([namespace, page.resource], html: { class: "form" }) do |f| %>

  <!-- User fields -->

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Woojit fields</legend>
    <%= f.fields_for @woojit do |ff| %>
      <%= render 'woojit_fields', f: ff %>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

So when I submit the form, what I'm hoping to see is a params hash with this subset:

```
{
  "user" => {
    "woojit_attributes" => {
       "attr_1"=>"Foo", # etc
    }
  }
}
```

But what I'm actually getting in the create action is a params hash with this subset:

```
{
  "user" => {
    "woojit" => {
       "attr_1"=>"Foo", # etc
    }
  }
}
```

Ie 'woojit' instead of 'woojit_attributes'. I could hack this in the create action, but that seems like a horrible way of resolving the problem. I want to know why the key is getting mis-named to begin with.

I originally tried the alternative of using the line `<%= f.fields_for :woojit do |ff| %>` (ie symbol instead of instance var), and not building a Woojit object in the #new action.

The [#fields_for guide](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) suggests in the One-To-One section that this should work, but the code in the block was never executed, so the line returned `nil` - and the woojit params never made it to the create action in any form.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was apparently that #fields_for behaves differently when given an instance of a model (`@woojit`), rather than a symbol (`:woojit`).

In the former instance it generates fields that reference (model name), eg:

```
<input type="text" name="user[woojit][woojit_attr]" id="user_pledge_pledgor_name" />
```

In the latter instance it generates fields fields that reference the model attributes, eg:

```
<input type="text" name="user[woojit_attributes][woojit_attr]" id="user_pledge_attributes_pledgor_name" />
```

Hope that saves someone some of the frustration I've just been through!